# Нет компонента Analysis Services в мастере установки SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Хочу установить сервер для многомерной базы. Почитал на сайте microsoft, посмотрел видосы, везде люди заходят в мастер установки SQL Server, доходят до выбора компонентов и ставят там галочку около "Analysis Services", а у меня такого компонента нет и никак он не показывается. Сервер 2014 версии, потому что windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Все в порядке, дело в было в том, что у меня стоял **EXPRESS** сервер, а нужен был **DEVELOPER EDITION**